# Do I need to add Fonts(A file which is along with Bootstrap files) file in html file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner to html. I want to use Bootstrap in my project. I did it download and got three files named as:
1)css
2)js
3)fonts
I have knowledge to add css and js files in my html file through  tag.But I am confuse about fonts file.Here's my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="jquery/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
//code
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you DO NOT have to add the fonts manually to your DOM or import it into your CSS file.

Just add the css file and the JS file to your DOM and place the font file next to the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are referenced by CSS files, not HTML files.

This is why the Bootstrap documentation told you to reference the CSS and JS but not the fonts in your HTML.